# How to open multiple .bin files

Tags: archiving

I have downloaded a series of `.bin` files, which supposed to be a collection of retro music videos:

[image: .bin files]

But I have no idea how to extract or open them. I've tried some suggestions that google gave me, but none of them worked. Any ideas what what these `.bin` files are and how to extract videos from them?

**Edit**

Result from trID file scanner:

[image]

Comment: .bin is one of those annoyingly misused file extentions - you're unlikely to be able to tell what they are - I'd likely start by scanning the files with [trid](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)

Comment: @Journeyman Geek thx for the tip, I've updated the question with scan result. http://freearc.org/Download.aspx did the trick. If you post your suggestion as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trid seems to indicate that [freearc](http://freearc.org/) should handle them. On the other hand, chances are these are 'standard' bin files - that is to say, they're cd disk images, but missing cue files so other archives may work as well (In your shoes, I'd have hit it with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) *second*) just to see what would happen. I also note those are non standard icons so you may already have something that handles it.

I'd note that trid is awesome in this situation, and working out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The files are archives in the ARC format as pointed out by TrID. ARC was a popular file compression format in the DOS era, in the times before ZIP became widespread.

Of all the [file archiviers that still support the ARC format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_archivers#Archive_format_support) WinZip or IZArc seem to be the most common. Try ‘unarcing’ the files and see what you’ll get. If you’re lucky the archives contain files a powerful media player can read. It is also possible that you’ll get raw data used to control a sound chip (like SID files from C64 chiptunes) or raw PCM data which require to figure out samling rate and bit depth to play it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [7 Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) , Right click on file `Open with 7 Zip`